# how to set different leading space for different devices using interface builder

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want a button to be positioned in a phone 100px away from left side and in other phone 200px away from left side.

so basically my questions is how to achieve these kind of requirements in Autolayout with xib or storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html). Then you can set whole autolayout specifically to the device you are targeting.

Comment: can you give me steps

Comment: What kind of devices are you targeting?

Comment: Step 1 - completely read the Size Classes document. Step 2 - ask specific question after reading the document.

Comment: iPhone 4s and old iPhones

Comment: iPhone 4S and older iPhone's than iPhone 4S have 3,5 inch screen sizes, so they are all compact size (in width), so Size Classes will not be a solution for you, and it can't be done directly in Storyboard or XIB. You can only control layout between landscape and portrait modes.

Answer (score 1):

Select the UI element you want to change:

[image]

Double click the constraint you want to change which will bring up something like

[image]

Click the little `(+)` and select the appropriate size class

[image]

[image]

Enter a value for that constraint on the added size class

[image]

> Your leading space will be -20 on all classes except for Compact/Compact where the space would be -100

Of course you have to figure out which constraint and which size class you exactly have to change - the basic workflow will however stay the same.

Comment: how to set thet different leading space for different devices in xib or storyboard ?

Comment: Did you read my answer? Different size classes = different device sizes